# AWS policy interpretation

Tags: amazon-web-services, permissions, policy

I am trying to understand the need for the condition `"home/${aws:userid}/*"` . This condition actually feels like it is satisified in the   `"arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/home/${aws:userid}/*" .`

When we have allowed for all s3 operations in the third statement for that user. then why do we need to allow s3:listbuckets specifically for that user?

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "",
                        "home/",
                        "home/${aws:userid}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/home/${aws:userid}",
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/home/${aws:userid}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

ref https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_examples_s3_federated-home-directory-console.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s3:ListBucket` is a bucket-level permission, while `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/home/${aws:userid}/*` is a wildcard **object** ARN, not a **bucket** ARN.

An attempt to grant `s3:ListBucket` will not match any `Resource` that isn't a bucket ARN, so the `s3:*` grant -- which only includes object ARNs -- does not actually allow object listings.

So this example policy does not contain any redundancy.

If this implementation still seems a bit counter-intuitive or perhaps convoluted, it does become somewhat clearer if you consider how the S3 API works on the wire. The [`ListObjects` API action](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html) (as well as the newer `ListObjectsV2`) is submitted against the bucket -- there's no path in the request... or, more precisely, the path in the HTTP request is always¹ `/`... and the query string contains `prefix=` and the object key prefix where the requested listing is to be anchored.

While there's no compulsory correlation between the way the underlying API works and the way IAM policies work, it does make sense that the `s3:prefix` condition key is what's used to control use of the `prefix` parameter to ListObjects, instead of an object-level ARN, and that the bucket -- not an object key or wildcard pattern -- is the resource being accessed.

---

¹ always `/` except when it's `/${bucket}` as required by the old deprecated path-style URLs that are [finally being phased out](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/storage/update-to-amazon-s3-path-deprecation-plan/) after a false start or two, at least for new buckets.  The resource as expressed in the path component of the request URI is always the bucket itself, not the bucket plus a key prefix.

Answer (score 0):

The resources are different. In the third statement, user can only access `bucket-name/home/${aws:userid}`. This means that when the user goes into the S3 console, and clicks bucket `bucket-name` it will get access denied. So user won't be able to **list the bucket content**, and will not see that there is `home` folder there. They will also not see that in `bucket-name/home` there is a folder with their username.

Thus, to overcome this issue, there is the second statement, which allows to list all content of ``bucket-name`and then`bucket-name/home`. This way users can **navigate easily** in S3 console to get to their actual home folder.

Without the second statement, users would have to type url of their home folders in browser to go to directly to it, which is not very user friendly.

Comment: thank you for the reply. 
I agree that " "" ,
                        "home/", are needed for browsing. but the resource arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name combined with the condition  "home/${aws:userid}/*" gives the same resource isn't it?

Comment: arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name prefixed with  "home/${aws:userid}/*"
is the same as
"arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/home/${aws:userid}/*" isn't it ?

Comment: @gkbinary Yes it is. It seems to be redundant, but this would have to be verified. The policy is simple enough for testing in s3 console.

Comment: @gkbinary no, it is not redundant. `s3:ListBucket` is a bucket-level permission, while `arn:aws:s3:::bucket-name/home/${aws:userid}/*` is a wildcard *object* ARN, not a *bucket* ARN.  An attempt to grant `s3:ListBucket` will not match if any path is specified in `Resource` so `s3:*` here does not allow the object listings as you appear to assume.

Comment: @Michael - sqlbot Thank you very much. precise answer.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you for clarification. Would you mind providing an answer? It would be useful for the OP and future reference.